# Differences between のに, 関わらず, にも関わらず, and のにも関わらず

Tags: word-choice, parsing

In this sentence:

> だれとも電話をする必要がない**のにも関わらず**、私はその小さな物体が欲しくてたまらなかったものだ。

How can I parse のにも関わらず?
I know にも関わらず means "in spite of" but so does のに and 関わらず. So why use の in にも関わらず?

Also, what is the function of も in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it has も makes important difference. (noun)に関わらず means "regardless of (noun)" while (noun/stem of na-adj, verb, i-adj)にも関わらず means "in spite of", as is already mentioned.

As for の, you need it to norminalize a verb when it connects to に関わらず, and it's virtually optional when it comes to にも関わらず. However you can rephrase interrogative clauses like 行くか行かないかに関わらず as 行く行かないに関わらず.

Answer (score 1):

のに関わらず, にも関わらず のに and のにも関わらず share the same meaning. Meaning of they are **In spite of**.
のに has one other meaning.  The other meaning is *although*(even though).

Comment: Can the の in のにも関わらず function as an attributive particle?